# nginx conditional 414 error_page

Tags: nginx

My goal is to create different 414 error pages if the URI of the request from the user exceeds the maximum allowed by the server.  I've set up 3 such 414 error pages with the following format within my app; `414.html`, `414.json`, `414.xml`

I would like the html page to be displayed by default, but if the request being made is through json or xml, I want to serve the associated 414 page for the specified format.

The following is what additions I've made to my nginx configuration file thus far.

```
server {
  ...

  map $http_accept $my_file_type {
    default              "html";
    "~*application/json" "json";
    "~*application/xml"  "xml";
  }

  error_page 414 /414.$my_file_type;
  location = /414.$my_file_type {
    log_format my_format '$http_accept -- $my_file_type -- $request_filename';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log my_format;

    root /srv/www/myapp/current/public/;
  }
}
```

Thus far, by changing the default value from `html` to `json` and to `xml`, I am able to get each of these static pages to be served upon initiating a request which results in a 414 error, however the I've checked my `access.log` and the `$http_accept` value is always appearing as `-` and the `$request_filename` is always appearing as `/srv/www/myapp/current/public/414.html` rather than the actual filename that I passed in my request.

I can also add that the request made does have an 'Accept: application/json' header which is being passed from my curl statement to test for an appropriate response, but it's still appearing as `-` in my access.log and the `$request_filename` is still a 414 page as opposed to the actual file from my request.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.